# Why the PHP function fopen() and related variable behave differently in smarty templating engine?

Tags: php, smarty3

Consider the snippet code:

```
{if $showfile eq 'debug'}
    <pre>{php}
        if ( $fh = fopen('../logs/debug.log' , "r") ) {
            readfile('../logs/debug.log'); 
            fclose($fh);
        } else {
            echo "Error: debug file can not be read.";
        }
    {/php}</pre>
{/if}
```

Output the content in `debug.log` file but the below code:

```
{if $showfile eq 'debug'}
    <pre>{php}
        if ( $fh = fopen('../logs/'.$showfile.'.log' , "r") ) {
            readfile('../logs/'.$showfile.'.log'); 
            fclose($fh);
        } else {
            echo "Error: ".$showfile." file can not be read.";
        }
    {/php}</pre>
{/if}
```

showing me the following output:

```
Error:  file can not be read.
```

What is the problem? Why the `$showfile` variable become empty after the `{if $showfile eq 'debug'}` condition ...

Answer (score 1):

The `{php}` tags in Smarty have their own scope, like a PHP function. If you want to use the `$showfile` variable, you need to use the global keyword.

```
{php}
    global $showfile;
{/php}
```